# how to style a <ul> horizontally with its elements in columns?

Tags: css, html-lists

Consider this HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to get this result:

```
One    Three    Five
Two    Four     Six
```

Or this:

```
One      Four
Two      Five
Three    Six
```

Can this be done with **CSS only**?

Comment: Although it is old, this article is a fantastic read about your question: http://alistapart.com/article/multicolumnlists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS3 `column` would achieve what you are looking for, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5E6VC/) and [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count)

```
ul {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;  
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 20px;
}
```

As you can see it still requires vendor prefixes but is supported by all major browsers [can I use](http://caniuse.com/multicolumn)

**Edit**

To avoid breaking inside the `<li>` as @andrew commented on his answer about, add

```
li {
     -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
     -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
     column-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5E6VC/2/)

Comment: Happy to have helped and I've just updated the answer to fix the problem @AndrewTet pointed out in the comments to his answer

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can use inline block on the li elements and make their widths a certain percentage of the ul. Check out the codepen below for an example.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eCzKD

Comment: nice one, but elements are not ordered as in my example.

Comment: Ah, didn't see that. I assume you can't change the order of the elements, huh?

btw I don't have the rep to comment on the other answer, but it has issues if there is a different amount of text in each column. I think you could solve these by setting a height on each of the lis.

http://jsfiddle.net/5E6VC/1/